# ActiveX Can't Create Object

Tags: vb6

In my vb6 dll I keep getting this error

> Code: 429
>   ActiveX Can't create object

This is the code from my form

```
Dim objAS400Price As New ReportTester.clsAS400PriceDiscr
Set objAS400Price = New ReportTester.clsAS400PriceDiscr
lngRetVal = objAS400Price.Report("AS400 Price Discrepancy Report", "AS400 Price Discrepancy Report", "C:\Temp", "Excel", "MASTERYY", "tschock", "NONE", "Local", True, "TSchock@ashleyfurniture.com")
```

This is the connection object from the dll

```
Set objDBConn = CreateObject("DBConnections2.DataAccess")
```

I used regsvr32 to register "DBConnections2.dll" on my local machine but the error is still occurring.  Any suggestions to why this is happening?

Comment: Because you have registered a wrong DLL? Or your CreateObject code is wrong (or mistyped)? It can be many things. Look into working examples of the ActiveX component to see what you're doing wrong. It's very hard to give you a good answer without having access to your system.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you temporarily add a hard reference to the "DBConnections2.dll" through menu item Project->References.  You should see the DLL in the list of references and be able to select it.  If you do not, click the "Browse" button and add it.

Now create an early bound reference instead of using "CreateObject".  By stepping into functions that call this DLL you may be able to discern which object is not referenced.

However, if you're still unable to get to the bottom of the bad reference it is likely that the "DBConnections2.dll" has a reference to one or more dependent DLLs that you are either missing or do not have registered.  In that is the case you can use the Dependency Walker application to open the DLL and determine which DLL(s) references are listed as missing.

The Dependency Walker is available as an optional Tools install with Visual Basic 6.  You can also download it separately if you wish.